# How to get the result of an ImageMagick convert command as bitmap data

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am working on a project that will make a jigsaw puzzle from an image and present it to the user as separate pieces in a browser. I have done all the prototyping in Python. At the moment I can produce separate images for each puzzle piece.

As a last step I want to make a nice bevel on the pieces to make them look realistic. I found a ImageMagick convert command to do that just fine:

```
convert piece.png -alpha extract -blur 0x2 -shade 120x30 piece.png -compose Overlay -composite piece.png -alpha on -compose Dst_In -composite result.png
```

I execute the command by using os.system, but this is taking way too long to complete.

Can you give me an advice on a solution to execute the ImageMagick processing in the fastest way? I think that would involve executing the processing directly with the ImageMagick libraries, sending it the input bitmap data and receiving the result also as bitmap data. Then I can stream the result to user. The solution does not have to be Python.

Comment: How about giving us a piece of your puzzle to play with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I have just been looking at your command again - I kind of assumed it was sensible as you implied you got it from Anthony Thyssen's excellent ImageMagick Usage pages - however I see you are reading the image `piece.png` *three times* which it must be possible to avoid by using `-clone` or `-write MPR:save`. Let me experiment some more. I haven't got your jigsaw piece to test with, so I am in the dark here, but you must be able to change your command to something like this:

```
convert piece.png -write mpr:piece                      \
   \( +clone -alpha extract -blur 0x2 -shade 120x30 \)  \ 
   -compose Overlay -composite                          \
   mpr:piece -alpha on -compose Dst_In -composite result.png
```

**MPR** is a Memory Program Register, or basically a named lump of RAM that ImageMagick can read and write to. There are details and examples [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#mpr).

**Original Answer**

Three things spring to mind... which one, or which combination of things, will help depends on the specification of your CPU, memory and disks as well as the sizes of your pieces - none of which I know or can test,

Firstly, if you used the libraries, you would avoid the overhead of creating a new process to run the `convert` - so that should help, but if your pieces are large and the bottleneck is actually the processing, using the libraries will make little difference.

Secondly, if your images are large, the time to read them in off disk and write them back to disk may be what is killing your performance. To test this, I would create a small RAMdisk and store the images on there and see if that helps. It is a quick and relatively easy test.

Thirdly, I assume you are generating many pieces and you currently do them one after the other in a sequential fashion. If this is the case, I would definitely recommend going multi-threaded. Either do this in your code with your language's threading environment, or try out GNU Parallel which has always been brilliant for me. So, if you were going to do

```
convert piece1.png -alpha extract ... -composite result1.png
convert piece2.png -alpha extract ... -composite result2.png
convert piece3.png -alpha extract ... -composite result3.png
...
convert piece1000.png -alpha extract ... -composite result1000.png
```

just either send all those commands to GNU Parallel on its *stdin* and it will execute them all in parallel on as many cores as your CPU has like this

```
( 
  echo convert piece1.png ... -composite result1.png
  echo convert piece2.png ... -composite result2.png
  echo convert piece3.png ... -composite result3.png 
) | parallel
```

or build the command like this

```
parallel convert {} -alpha ..... result-{} ::: piece*.png
```

Comment: Hi Matk, thanks for your answer. I will try optimizing the command and use some multi threading technique. Still I would like to know how to make the bevel using the libraries. I expect the file handling and the call of a external program to be the main part of the total time needed to make the bevel.

Comment: I would expect the `system()` function to take under 15ms on a reasonable machine. How long does you processing take? How big are your images?